# Connecting directly to database with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, dbi, sequel

I am using heroku with Ruby on Rails. The data for my app however has to be copied from a different database. Initially I created the script in perl, but as I found out I cannot install the DBI perl module on the Heroku instance easily.

So right now I am trying to create a ruby script and then set it up on Heroku Scheduler to duplicate a subset of information to heroku database for me to run my app off of it.

I am not sure which gem I can use for my script though. I have found [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) which has not had any work done on it for a while. As well as [ruby-DBI](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-dbi/), That seems to have been updated in 2009. Are there ay other gems I could use or is it better to use one of the above. Both of the databases I will use are Postgres.

Comment: If you've got access to the database directly from your machine, you should be able to do your manipulation without touching the server. If this is not the case, write a rails endpoint where you can send the data to and have rails insert it into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem has commits as recent as 15 days. This would probably be your best choice.

Comment: +1 Sequel is a great ORM, and is actively being developed. And, the author of Sequel is a great fan of PostgreSQL so you can be sure it'll work with that DBM first.